# How to use Jgrapht library?

Tags: jgrapht

I want to use Jgrapht library in Java environment. but I dont know how to import it.
**the error is:**

> Error:(7, 1) java: package org.jgrapht.graph does not exist

How can I use it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7CfK.jpg)

Comment: edited my answer. If this answer is helpful, please upvote and accept the answer such that is is visible to other stackoverflow users.

Answer (score 3):

**For contributors:**
If you want to import jgrapht because you want to contribute to its development, then follow these instructions: https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/wiki/Contributor-Guidelines

**For users:**
If you want to import jgrapht to use it in your application, i.e. use jgrapht as a dependency, follow the instructions:
https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/wiki/How-to-use-JGraphT-as-a-dependency-in-your-projects